# Conky configuration woes

Tags: 10.04, configuration, conky

I am having trouble setting up conky to display my google calendar or a basic todo list and various system stats mainly memory and processors activity.

I would appreciate the steps to set this up.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this one http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/display-google-calendar-on-your-desktop.html

Answer (score 0):

To get google calendar to show up on your desktop install "gcalcli" from the repository and in your /home/yourusername/.conkyrc file put:

${exec gcalcli --nc calw 2}

that will display your calendar for the upcoming two weeks
to learn more type gcalcli into a terminal

as for system stats this page helped me alot: http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html